# Cut/snip/advanced crop an image with jQuery

Tags: jquery, image

Is there a library/jQuery plugin that would mimic what is seen here?

http://labs.byhook.com/kutout/

More specifically, we need the ability to simply cut out parts of an image as we desire (not confined to a rectangle or square)

Is there anything that already solves this problem?

Comment: Why you don't buy a paid plugin??

Comment: I'm willing to if I can find it. I wasn't able to after about 30 minutes of searching on Google. Do you have any that you would suggest?

Comment: ok try this:
https://github.com/cropzoom/cropzoom
but there is not proper documentation available.

Comment: Saw that one previously however it forces you to use a rectangle instead of simply drawing over what exactly you want to cut out.

Comment: this can also crop image & this is free also.

Comment: I see that it can crop, but our use requirement demands that it doesn't conform to a square or rectangle.

Comment: so do you need circular selection

Comment: Freehand selection is more accurate.